# windows batch file loop in strings

Tags: batch-file

I want to judge if input para is valid, and have a list of valid strings(saying "aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd" is correct), but I dislike to use if-else. I want a simple method to do this.
I like something such as:

```
set env=%1
for %%A in ("aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" ) do if "%env%"==%%A echo true else goto end
```

I don't know how to make this out.

What I want is like:

```
set env=%1
if "%env%"neq"aaa" and "%env%"neq"bbb" and "%env%"neq"ccc"and "%env%"neq"ddd" (
    goto end
)
```

Thank aschipfl and magoo.

My resolution is as:

```
for %%a in (aaa bbb ccc ddd ) do (
   if "%env%"=="%%a" (
    goto next    
   ) 
)
@echo Wrong parameter! 
goto end
:next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if a string is in a list of strings in a DOS batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235153/how-to-find-if-a-string-is-in-a-list-of-strings-in-a-dos-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I want to point out a basic issue of the `if`/`else` clause:

```dos
if "%env%"==%%A echo true else goto end
```

The parser treats the entire portion after the comparison expression as a single command line, hence if the comparison is positive, `true else goto end` is going to be echoed. To solve that you need to show the parser where the `if` statement ends by placing parentheses, like this...:

```dos
if "%env%"=="%%~A" (echo true) else goto end
```

...or this, if you want to spread it over multiple lines:

```dos
if "%env%"=="%%~A" (
    echo true
) else (
    goto end
)
```

In addition, I replaced `%%A` by `"%%~A"` to ensure that the right part of the comparison expression is always placed within quotes even in case you provided a list of strings like `"aaa" bbb "ccc" ddd`.

---

As far as I understand you want to go to `:end` in case the first argument `%1` does not match any of the given strings. There is a logical error in your code, because you will always jump to `:end` even if a match has been encountered (as there are still three mismatches then), so the `else` clause is for sure going to be executed (supposing you corrected the `if`/`else` syntax as described earlier).

You could change the code as follows (using a `FLAG` variable indicating that a match has been found):

```dos
set "FLAG="
for %%A in ("aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd") do (
    if "%~1"=="%%~A" (
        set "FLAG=true"
    )
)
if not defined FLAG goto :end
rem // Execution continues here in case a match has been found...
```

Alternatively, you could do this (using another `goto` to leave the loop):

```dos
for %%A in ("aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd") do (
    if "%~1"=="%%~A" (
        goto :found
    )
)
goto :end
:found
rem // Execution continues here in case a match has been found...
```

Note that the above code snippets do case-sensitive string comparisons; to change that, use `if /I`.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you're trying to do, but the code you've presented will echo `true else goto end` if the comparison is true.

```
if "%env%"==%%A (echo true) else (goto end)
```

will echo `true` on a match, otherwise go to `end`. The positioning of the brackets is critical - `) else (` must be on the same physical line.